# Wireless Access Point with login/landing page

Tags: wireless, internet-connection, hot-spot

I´m investigating how to setup a Wireless Access Point in a Linux (Ubuntu, in my case) PC where is mandatory to login/register using a backend module that I have developed.

I know that exist some software solutions like Chilli or Easyhotspot that may satisfy the requirements for most people, but I want to implement a custom solution. The workflow should be as follows:

When the user tries to connect to Internet via my Wireless Access Point a custom landing page always appears. In other words, the Wireless Access Point must redirect always to a (for example) index.html page.

The page contains a login/registration form that points to some backend endpoints.

The backend endpoints that enable login and registration are my own and are deployed in a Web server.

If the login/registration operation is success then the user get Internet access.

I´ve read ton of blog posts, forum threads, etc. but I found nothing. What I want to do looks simple, but I don´t know how to develop something like that. I don´t mind if I have to develop that solution in Python, C, Bash scripting... Any tutorial, tips, suggestions would be very appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Best regards,

Luis Cappa.